# Why is my kivy dropdown menu not showing up (Python)?

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, kivy

I am currently trying to make a vocabulary trainer with kivy so I can use it on my phone. But I am somehow stuck at the dropdown menu. I used the dropdown menu sample from the kivy wiki and made a few changes so it fits into my existing code. 
My problem is now that the dropdown menu doesn't show up and python doesn't give me an error either. I already tried some other possible solutions which also didn't work for me as well as debugging via try - except and the pycharm debugger.

```
class FloatLayout(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FloatLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.dropdown = DropDown()
        self.languages = ["language1", "language2", "language3"]
        for i in self.languages:
            btn = Button(text="%r" % i, size_hint_y=None, height=30)
            btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: self.dropdown.select(btn.text))
            self.dropdown.add_widget(btn)

        self.dropdownButton = Button(text="Language selection", size_hint=(None, None), pos_hint={"x": 0.5, "top": 0.5})
        self.dropdownButton.bind(on_release=self.dropdown.open)
        self.dropdown.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(self.dropdownButton, "text", x))
class KivyGUI(App):
    def build(self):
        return FloatLayout()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    runKivy()
```

All help and is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem 1

Need to add the `self.dropdownButton` to the root widget, `FloatLayout`.

```
self.add_widget(self.dropdownButton)
```

## Problem 2

Replace `runKivy()` with `KivyGUI().run()`

## Snippets

```
        self.dropdown.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(self.dropdownButton, "text", x))
        self.add_widget(self.dropdownButton)

class KivyGUI(App):
    def build(self):
        return FloatLayout()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    KivyGUI().run()
```

## Output

[image: Result]